# Matlab: Get graphics object's name

Tags: matlab

Some (graphics) objects in Matlab seem to have "names". For example, if I create a plot `plot(1,1)` and give it a title `title('mytitle')` and then access the current axes via `gca` I get the following answer:

```
ans = 

  Axes (mytitle) with properties:

             XLim: [0 2]
             YLim: [0 2]
           XScale: 'linear'
           YScale: 'linear'
    GridLineStyle: '-'
         Position: [0.1300 0.1100 0.7750 0.8150]
            Units: 'normalized'

  Show all properties
```

You can see that in parentheses we have "mytitle". How can I access this string?

I know that in this case, I could just get the title string, but I want to know how to generally access this name.

I'm running Matlab R2016a

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the "Show all properties" (or calling `get(gca)`) you get a complete list of all properties of the current axes. The "Title" property is what your looking for.

Calling `t = get(gca,'Title')` you'll get all properties of the Title object, and you can access the string by calling `t.String`.